# Adjektiv Deklination

Tags: grammar-style

In the sentence

> Jede Verwertung in anderen als den gesetzlich zugelassenen Fällen...

why is it **gesetzlich** and not **gesetzlichen**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short anwer**

Here, *gesetzlich* is not declined, because it is used as an adverb, not as an adjective.

**Adjective**

> than the legal allowed cases → als den gesetzlich**en** zugelassen**en** Fällen

Here, the cases are allowed and legal. Therefore, both *zugelassen**en*** (allowed) and *gesetzlich**en*** (legal) are adjectives, which must be appropriately declined.

**Adverb**

> than the legally allowed cases → als den gesetzlich zugelassen**en** Fällen

Here, however, the the cases are legally allowed. Therefore, *gesetzlich* (legally) is an adverb that modifies the adjective *zugelassenen* (allowed). German adverbs are not declined.

Comment: It should be noted that "gesetzlich" (-"lawful", "legal") shows up in a dictionary as an adjective. But most adjectives can be used as adverbs in German without change, unlike English which requires the "-ly" suffix. Context, and the fact that adverbs are not declined, allow you to figure out what it refers to. Here it's not the cases that are legal, but the way they're allowed that's legal. In English, "legally allowed cases" rather than "legal, allowed cases".

Comment: @RDBury, thank you for your comment. I rewrote my answer and hope that it is clearer now.